# Make a VSTO Excel 2016 Workbook Application portable/without setup?

Tags: excel, installation, ms-office, vsto

**I have the following situation:**

I developed a VSTO Excel 2016 Workbook, which triggers some code when you copy/paste an Excel Worksheet in the above mentioned Workbook. When i publish the project (Project Properties > Publish > Publish Now), Visual Studio creates the following in Folder:

1. Excel Workbook(.xlsx)
2. VSTO file(.vsto)
3. setup.exe file

The Workbook only opens without error when i first run the Setup, wich obviously installs the .vsto file.

**My Question:**

Can you generate/publish a .xlsx Workbook which is portable, i.e. you dont have to install anything since the Code is already in the .xlsx file? Because I dont want to run the setup.exe everytime when i switched to another PC.

Or is there even an alternative solution to VSTO/my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to embed and distribute code with a workbook is to use VBA.

There is no way to embed a VSTO solution in a workbook - VSTO was explicitly designed to *not* allow that for reasons of code maintenance and security.